# Cumulative distribution function for N iid random variables

Tags: probability

Suppose there are $N$ iid $X_i$. The distribution function for each of the $X_i$ is discrete (with $m$ different outcomes taken from $\{x_i\}$ each with probability $p_i$)

If $C$ is a constant, what is

$$
P\left( \sum_i^N X_i < C \right) \; \text{?}
$$

Further, does this problem decouple into some kind of product or sum?

Comment: Are you looking for an exact result or an approximation?

Comment: Also, can we assume that the $x_i\geqslant 0$, or may they be negative?

Comment: I'd like to know if this problem has a closed solution for the X_i following a general discrete distribution.

Comment: For discrete random variables with finite number of support points, the support points of the sum of $N$  i.i.d. copies of them must be finite as well. So technically speaking the pmf must be "closed", but it may need to rely on computer to do the complex calculation. It depends on how to you interpret "close". The CDF can always be expressed as a piecewise function, but you may not get a simple formula for it. Is it close?